# jQuery Modal Window Not Firing on Second Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why isn't this jQuery firing up clicking the "Legal" link? It works for the "Add..." Link..

> **HTML**>

```
<div id="top_function">
    <div class="functions" style="margin-top:7px;"><img src="img/addProfIcon.png"  width="32" height="32" />
        <h4><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" class="poplight">Add...</a></h4><!-- ADD PROF/COURSE -->
    </div><!--function1-->
    <!--<div class="functions"><img src="img/disclaimerIcon.png"  width="32" height="32" /><h4><a href="#">Compare</a></h4></div>--> 
    <div class="functions"><img src="img/disclaimerIcon.png"  width="32" height="32" />
        <h4><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name2" class="poplight2">Legal</a></h4>
    </div><!--function3--> <!-- LEGAL -->
    <div class="functions"><img src="img/contactIcon.png"  width="32" height="32" /><h4><a href="#">Contact</a></h4></div><!--function4--> <!-- CONTACT -->
</div>
```

> **Modal.js**>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="img/close.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

    return false;
});

//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

**Actual Contents of Modal Window (For Now):**

Test

Answer (score 0):

You only set the click handler on anchor tags with class `poplight`. Your "Legal" link has class `poplight2` instead.

Comment: Not that easy, each class and div has its own set of data in it. By doing poplight (2x) .. it displays the same set of data

Comment: @user700070: Huh? I'm just explaining why your code isn't "working". You have the above inconsistency.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is `poplight2` is there for a reason since each link pops up a new modal window with different content so content in `poplight` is different than `poplight2`

Comment: @user700070: OK, fine. So set your event handlers on elements of that class, too. At present, you have no event handlers on elements of class `poplight2`, and that's why nothing is happening when you click on them.